# Delay loop in Python

Tags: python

At first I want to say that I have about two days of coding experience so please don't expect too much :)

To start with what I'm trying to achieve:

I want a program that "types" a shortcut every time Spotify changes the song and with a lot copy and paste from [here](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/spotify-notifications/) I came up with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

BUS_NAME='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify'

import subprocess
import dbus, urllib.request
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GObject

def dbus_signal_receiver(interface, changes, sig):
   if dbus.String('Metadata') in changes:
       subprocess.run(["/home/user/Scripts/shortcut.sh"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
   DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
   bus = dbus.SessionBus()
   bus.add_signal_receiver(dbus_signal_receiver, path='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2', bus_name=BUS_NAME)
   loop = GObject.MainLoop()
   loop.run()
```

But I have 2 Problems:

1: If I run this program it tells me this and while I know what it means I don't know how to fix it (even though it works like this).

```
/home/lorenz/Scripts/LatestApproach.py:23: PyGIDeprecationWarning: GObject.MainLoop is deprecated; use GLib.MainLoop instead
  loop = GObject.MainLoop()
```

2:  And that's the bigger problem, every time the song changes, Dbus outputs the change 6 times and because of that the shortcut is "pressed" 6 times in about a second. So I tried to add a delay of 2 seconds with time.sleep but it always ended up pressing the shortcut every 2 seconds.

And at this point I'm out of ideas so every help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution, even though without a delay. Now the script checks if the changes send by dbus are actually different.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

BUS_NAME='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify'
b = "somerandomstuff"

import time
import subprocess
import dbus, urllib.request
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from gi.repository import GObject

def dbus_signal_receiver(interface, changes, sig):
    global b
    metadata = changes[dbus.String('Metadata')]
    if dbus.String('Metadata') in changes:
        a = str(metadata[dbus.String('xesam:title')])
        if a != b:
            subprocess.run(["/home/user/Scripts/shortcut.sh"])
            b = a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    bus.add_signal_receiver(dbus_signal_receiver, path='/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2', bus_name=BUS_NAME)
    loop = GObject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

And the fact that the loop is deprecated doesn't bother me for now since it works perfectly fine.